# How to log the URL scheme (http / https) in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

nginx has the `$scheme` variable usable in its `log_format` lines.

`%H` is the request protocol (e.g. "HTTP/1.1").

How can I do the same with Apache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is to have two conditional `CustomLog` directives, controlled by whether the `HTTPS` variable is set.

```
CustomLog logs/access.log "https://..." env=HTTPS
CustomLog logs/access.log "http://..." env=!HTTPS
```

I have also tried using `SetEnvIf` in the following manner, but it doesn't work (it logs `-`):

```
SetEnv URL_SCHEME=http
SetEnvIf HTTPS on URL_SCHEME=https
CustomLog logs/access.log "%{URL_SCHEME}e://..."
```

Comment: your `mod_env` endeavors may have failed because of [syntactical errors](http://serverfault.com/questions/359476/how-to-log-the-url-scheme-http-https-in-apache/359482#359482). `SetEnv` takes its variable and value without an equal sign: `SetEnv URL_SCHEME http`.

Comment: also, the `SetEnvIf` line does not work on apache < 2.4.1 because `mod_setenvif` apparently has [no access to the ssl environment](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49057). almost drove me crazy on 2.2.22.

Comment: This environment variable seems specific to mod_ssl. If you use another module, such as mod_gnutls, you do not have it.

Comment: Also, `mod_ssl` only sets the environment variable if you explicitly tell it to do so via [`SSLOptions`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#ssloptions).

Answer (score 7):

This works for me with Apache 2.4.23:

```
LogFormat "%{REQUEST_SCHEME}x ..." my_log_format
```

`%{varname}x` is only available when mod_ssl is loaded, see: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#logformats

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html documents this variable.

Comment: Where's %{VARNAME}x documented though? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html doesn't mention x variables. Confirmed working though.

Comment: IMHO, This should be the accepted answer. :-)

Answer (score 3):

For some reason I could not get the examples above to work, so found another way: you can add 2 rewrite rules into your configuration as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=SCHEME:HTTP]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=SCHEME:HTTPS]
```

Then add this into your LogFormat definition.

```
scheme=\"%{SCHEME}e\"
```

Answer (score 3):

As the url scheme is not directly available in apache log format, you may log the canonical port (e.g. 80/443) of the server serving the request by using %p as an alternative:

```
CustomLog access.log "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\" port:%p"
```

Comment: How did this get two upvotes so quickly? Anyway, this is not useful if you want to effectively log requests' URLs, for which you need the protocol URI scheme.

Comment: The port indicates the protocol.

Comment: well ports can be changed so it's only viable if you use default ports though.

Answer (score -2):

Define your log output and add %H to it. This is the same for Apache.

So, you build a `LogFormat` like this and afaik there are a couple defined in the default apache configuration.

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
```

and add the name of the LogFormat (in this case "common") to the end of your logfile call

```
CustomLog logs/access_log common
```

Just look here for further informations about the [log](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html) and [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats) about the different format strings.

Comment: Um... I've already looked there. I stated in my question that `%H` does not do what I need.