# Apache (http) behind load balancer (http/https) - Redirect does not preserve https

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing, redirect, https

I have two configurations - development and staging - with (supposedly) identical configurations: a set of HTTP-only Apache instances sitting behind a Citrix load balancer that allows both HTTP and HTTPS connections.

The Apache VirtualHost definitions contain the following directives:

```
RedirectMatch permanent /something/endpoint(.*)$ /something/otherendpoint$1
SSLProxyEngine On
ProxyPass /something/endpoint !
ProxyPass /something https://192.168.1.100:6443/something
<Location /something>
ProxyPassReverse https://192.168.1.100:6443/something
</Location>
```

So, I want to proxy any requests for `/something` to a different backend HTTPS server, except for `/something/endpoint`, which I need to redirect.

Now, everything is working fine in my development environment.  I can access `http://hostname/something/endpoint` and it will redirect me to `http://hostname/something/otherendpoint`. Likewise, I can access `https://hostname/something/endpoint` and it will redirect me to `https://hostname/something/otherendpoint`.

But in the staging environment, both `http://hostname/something/endpoint` and `https://hostname/something/endpoint` redirect to `http://hostname/something/otherendpoint` - it does not preserve HTTPS.

I have been pulling my hair out trying to figure out what the difference is between the two configurations. There must be something causing Apache to not respect the access protocol, but I'm not able to isolate it. The HTTP response headers look the same in both environments, except for the redirect `Location` header that specifies `http` instead of `https`.

Any ideas about what configuration difference could be causing this?

Comment: Do you have any differences in other apache configs outside vhosts? Does your balancer do SSL termination? If you terminate SSL on balancer, validate if balancer is routing HTTPS requests to HTTPS port on your backend web servers. You can check what is the schema in request by logging it using %{REQUEST_SCHEME}x in your LogFormat, to confirm what you receive on web servers. See David Caldwell answer on this thread http://serverfault.com/questions/359476/how-to-log-the-url-scheme-http-https-in-apache. With your RedirectMatch definition pay attention to generating self-referential URLs. Read the

Comment: Read the ServerName and UseCanonicalName directives description https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#servername. Share some details how you already troubleshoot this issue, to not go through the same here. As a quick solution, you can set result URL in RedirectMatch directive with schema and FQDN explicitly.

Comment: I don't believe there are any other apache config differences.  Yes, the load balancer is responsible for SSL termination, and proxies that traffic to the backend servers via HTTP.  So I suppose it's unsurprising that the generated redirect location is http://  - however it's strange that the two environments differ in behavior.  One would assume the load balancer is modifying that header to match to the requested protocol, but I'm not sure (and doesn't explain why the two environments differ). I do not want to set the FQDN explicitly because there are multiple server aliases.

Comment: Could you post an obscured version of the relevant apache configs for the sites and global? That will help us better help you see if there is a config issue with apache.

Answer (score 0):

Please remember that permanent redirects get cached by your webbrowser, you will need to either manually clear the browser cache after each test/modification in your configuration or test in "incognito"/"anonymous" browser windows.

How [apache httpd merges configuration directives](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#merging) can be a bit tricky. 
The syntax you're using seems a bit inconsistent and might be the cause of your issues:

```
ProxyPass /something https://192.168.1.100:6443/something
<Location /something>
ProxyPassReverse https://192.168.1.100:6443/something
</Location>
```

For clarity please use either:

```
ProxyPass /something/endpoint !
ProxyPass /something https://192.168.1.100:6443/something
ProxyPassReverse /something https://192.168.1.100:6443/something
```

or enclose everything in  `Location` directives:

```
<Location /something>
  ProxyPass  https://192.168.1.100:6443/something
  ProxyPassReverse https://192.168.1.100:6443/something
</Location>
<Location /something/endpoint>
  ProxyPass  "!"
  Redirect permanent /something/otherendpoint
</Location>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am testing with incognito, definitely not a caching issue.  Part of the formatting/order of the directives is decided by the Puppet Apache module, so I don't have direct control over that unless I keep adding to `custom_fragment`...which is possible...but the fact that the virtualhost configuration is the same in both environments would point to something else as the root cause.  At the moment I'm leaning toward a load balancer configuration issue.